# Django: how to check if the users that are registered under me have new users registered under them in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am writing a referral system logic in django. The referral system works fine now, but what i want to implement is this. When i refer a user "**user 2**" and "**user 3**", it is stored that i have refered two users, now how do i check if "**user 2**" or "**user 3**" which are refered by me: have gotten a new user refered by them ("**user 2**" or "**user 3**").

in the profile model i have a field like this
models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    code = models.CharField(max_lenght=100, ...)
    recommended_by = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
```

What is the best way to achieve this kind of feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Profile model link to User with OneToOne field(name 'user')? If Yes:

If you only want two levels of nested recommended_by I would go with:

```
my_recomended = Profile.object.filter(recommeded_by=request.user).value_list('user__id', flat=True)
second_level_recommended=Profile.object.filter(recommeded_by__in=my_recomended)
```

Comment: okay that fixed it, now i would like to add some point to the main user, (not the user who refered the new user but the first user) when the new user gets created.

Comment: i have a model field called `indirect_sign_up = models.IntegerField(default=0)` in the `Profile Model`. how do i add some points say `50 points` for the main user?

Comment: On user registration check if indirect_user =new_user.profile.recomended_by.profile.recomeded_by is not None then increment indirect_user.profile.indirect_sign_up += 50 and save()